# Determine whether the following cosets are the same

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H=\{0,\pm 3, \pm 6, \pm, 9, \dots\}$. Using the property that $a+H=b+h$ if and only if $b-a\in H$, determine if the following cosets are the same:

(a) $11+H$ and $17+H$

(b) $-1+H$ and $5+H$

I am not sure how to use the property. I can do it just adding each constant to the set $H$. If anybody can show me how to use the following property to answer the question I would appreciate it.

Comment: I wonder what you do not understand. Answer  is in question. $11+H=17+H$ if and only if $17-11\in H$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property, translated to apply directly to (a), says "$11 + H$ and $17 + H$ are the same coset if and only if $11-17$ is an element of $H$" Does this mean they are the same coset? And what about (b), can you do that on your own?